# Renaming feature classes in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop

I often have a problem when it comes to renaming featureclasses or SHPs in ArcGIS. I also have a problem when for example I have to transform 20 Feature classes or a whole dataset into a new coordinate system and want to append "_ETRS89" to the end of all the transformed feature classes.

I know there are python scripts which do this, as well variable substitution methods in model builder. But isn´t there also the option of putting this in the Tool´s dialog in ArcMap?

Comment: Could you review and revise the question, please?  Are you asking whether, without using Python and without using ModelBuilder, it is possible to [**Rename**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000056000000) or "transform" (which tool?) 20 feature classes with a string of "_ETRS89" concatenated onto the end of their name without having to type it 20 times?

Comment: Do I get you right?: You want an entry in the Menu that lets you rename (and/or transform) not only one single feature class, but a whole bunch of feature classes with a single action?

Comment: Basically I want to know how to append a string to the end of Featureclass names. In my workflow however, this is usually only necessary when I have to reproject several feature classes in a Featuredataset beacause I then have to append the coordinate system to the end of the filename. ArcGIS appends "_project" to the end of the data after a reproject. I want "_ETRS". I hope this is clear now.

Comment: It makes it a little clearer but can you use the edit button to revise your question with this detail, please?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a tool in model builder and want to run it from the tools menu (rather than open model builder all the time), you need to define parameters.  These will then show up in a dialog box when you click on the tool n the tools menu (as opposed to edit it in model builder).  See the [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002w0000007v000000) for how to do this.  You can then use the tool from the tools menu like any other tool.

So, you can take your python script and add it to a tool using model builder.  Give it some inputs which you should mark as parameters and perhaps likewise have a parameter for the string you want to append as a file name.  You will also want to parameterize your folder destination.